# Kafka HDFS Connector Java Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to connect my Kafka to HDFS, but when I run the configuration, I get the following error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.close(HdfsSinkTask.java:121)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSinkTask.java:339)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.closePartitions(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:154)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:146)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:190)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm running the task on Landoop web UI :

[image: UI Screenshot]

Anybody know where this mistake might have come from? Thanks

Comment: Please add the properties files as text, not images. Also the worker properties for kafka connect

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*